# Midori shuts down

Tags: midori

I like Midori, but there is one big problem. It crashes too much:

```
(midori4:2): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(midori4:2): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(midori4:2): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(midori4:2): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(midori4:2): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(midori4:2): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(midori4:2): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(midori4:2): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(midori4:2): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(midori4:2): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

parent is shutting down, bye...
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: I recommend you try Firefox or Chrome since Midori is outdated

Comment: I already changed to Firefox. Hope they will fix this problem, because Midori is much faster than Firefox, Chrome etc.. Thx  Stefan

Comment: How old is this computer . My laptop is 3 years old and Chrome is faster than Midori

Comment: Sorry, for answering your pot very late. I removed elementary os from my laptop and now I am back again :)

Comment: I changed to firefox, too, but still using midori  occasionally,  because its very fast